# Set image to the listview from intent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, imageview, uri

I have list view with image and text and I can call gallery intent onClick.

here ih my custom row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10px"
            android:layout_marginTop="4px"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@+id/label" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and main code:

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ListView lv;
    private ArrayList<String> itemArray;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter;

    //new gallery intent privates
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private String selectedImagePath;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        itemArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemArray.clear();

        itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.label, itemArray);
        setListAdapter(itemAdapter);

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        if( uri == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if( cursor != null ){
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // select a file
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }

    protected void addItemList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        itemArray.add(0,"step");
        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    // menu options
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        menu.add("add");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        addItemList();
        Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

How can I set selected image to the clicked list item imageView? Can't find any solution how to connect them/
(I know how to load images if I know their dirrectory (I don't need it here), but I don't know how to set them after an intent)

Comment: are you getting  image set in your listview image??

Comment: I need to set selected imege to the ImageView in row.xml. I have @drawable/ic_launcher in it before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste below code in your onActivityResult method :

```
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                photo.setImageBitmap(photo);                
            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: photo is an ImageView? How can I find it?

Comment: Bitmap photo; It is an object of "Bitmap"

Comment: Are you aware about custom listview & custom adapter? if not then go for few basic examples of custom listview soon you will get to know about your problem.

Comment: Now I set an image to the image view - but, all images was set to the first list item not to choosen one, how can I change that?

Comment: Keep one array of bitmaps. Then you need to use 'position' variable of onListItemClick for setting image/bitmap to particular list item.